# String functions

Tags: c#, string

I want to search for a given string, within another string (Ex. find if "something" exists inside "something like this". How can I do the following? :

1. Know the position in which "something" is located (in the curr. ex. this is = 0.
2. Extract everything to the left or to the right, up to the char. found (see 1).
3. Extract a substring beggining where the sought string was found, all the way to X amount of chars (in Visual Basic 6/VBA I would use the Mid function).

Answer (score 10):

```
string searched = "something like this";
```

1.

```
int pos = searched.IndexOf("something");
```

2.

```
string start = searched.Substring(0, pos);
string endstring = searched.Substring(pos);
```

3.

```
string mid = searched.Substring(pos, x);
```

Comment: @bdukes: thanks for the edit, I was still missing the quotes around "something" afterwards.

Comment: Number 2 wont work since you are not taking into account the lenght of "something".  Using the split method is easier.

Comment: @Igor: Depends on your interpretation of #2. "up to the char. found (see 1)." to me, means what was returned by IndexOf.  For your interpretation, your method is valid.

Comment: Works great. How can I code this into a class, that becomes publicly available to any Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the String.SubString() method?  You can use the IndexOf() method to see if the substring exists first.

Comment: Yes, that works too, but the OP was looking for a way to extract the substring. Contains() would only tell him whether it could be found. IndexOf would be more useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members(VS.71).aspx) member functions, in particular the [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(VS.71).aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`int String.IndexOf(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
string s = "I have something like this";

//question No. 1
int pos = s.IndexOf("something");  

//quiestion No. 2
string[] separator = {"something"};
string[] leftAndRightEntries = s.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);  

//question No. 3

int x = pos + 10;
string substring = s.Substring(pos, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using Split, as it's designed to give you multiple results. I would stick with the code in the first example, though the second block should actually read...

```
string start = searched.Substring(0, pos);
string endstring;

if(pos < searched.Length - 1)
endstring = searched.Substring(pos + "something".Length);
else
endstring = string.Empty
```

The key difference is accounting for the length of the string to find (hence the rather odd-looking "something".Length, as this example is designed for you to be able to plop in your own variable).